# Adding subelement with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

The below code, which should add a subelemenet to a given XML element, gives the error:

> xml.SubElement(new,xml.Element(self.XMLEntriesList['RiverCallPower']))
>   TypeError: must be xml.etree.ElementTree.Element, not None

But when I check, the element in question is confirmed to be an `Element`, and not `None`.

```
self.XMLEntriesList['RiverCallPower']
Out[3]: Element 'RiverCallPower' at 0x04B83420
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
    self.tree = xml.parse('strategies.xml')
    self.root = self.tree.getroot()
    ...
    new=self.root.append(xml.Element('newElement'))
    xml.SubElement(new,xml.Element(self.XMLEntriesList['RiverCallPower']))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is not in the `XMLEntriesList['RiverCallPower']` part, but the `new` variable that is `None`. And that happen because [`append()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.append) simply adds the new element to the list of root element's children and doesn't return anything. Try this way :

```
.......
new = xml.Element('newElement')
self.root.append(new)
xml.SubElement(new,xml.Element(self.XMLEntriesList['RiverCallPower']))
```